# Allow Remote Connection to only ONE database SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I would like to have 2 db (Dev & Prod). CarsDevDB & CarsDB. 
I have 2 users, CarsDevUser (Allow Remote Access, Port 5000) and CarsAdmin (only allow local connection).

I would like to connect to CarsDevDB with the user CarsDevUser from anywhere REMOTELY using (IP):5000.

However, I would like to connect to CarsDB using ONLY LOCAL connection. 
127.0.0.1. CarsDB/CarsAdmin should NOT have any remote connection whatsoever.

CarsDevUser will not access to any other database.

How can I proceed with this? I've enabled Remote connection and got it to work, I can't limit it to one database yet though.

Comment: Can't you just only grant explicit access to this one database? What server role(s) is CarsDevUser in?

Comment: What Aaron said plus just make CarsAdmin a local windows account and create the login from that.

Comment: How would I do that? If possible, I wouldn't mind turning off the remote connection but give only THIS database the remote access (if possible). CarDevUser current only has "public" server role. What else should I add? I guess I should just make the prod DB "Window Account Only" access and the other dev db SQL authentication?

Comment: Combination Server Roles and Schema access can make this happen, please hire a senior DBA, to help with that :)